# Failed to configure cloudera manager agent

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Hi I am new to bigdata and I am installing cloudera manager 7.4.4 on RHEL 8.0. While setting up the cluster I am facing the error like "failed to configure clouder manager agent" Can anyone help me to resolve the issue.
Thank you.

[image: example1]

[image: example2]